# is there any relevance to the random text found in the last log entry on the computer terminal ". .. . aa@dxp0892jl;asdfmn;3ujpl12j;1"?

Tags: chronos

is there any relevance to the random text found in the last log entry for one of the people plugged into the matrix? This is back in the 'real world' behind the door that requires a keycard.

text stream is ". .. . aa@dxp0892jl;asdfmn;3ujpl12j;1"

[image]